# Python dependency management best practices

Tags: python, package, dependency-management

I have a little Python side project which is experiencing some growing pains, wondering how people on larger Python projects manage this issue.

The project is Python/Flask/Docker deployed to AWS. Listed dependencies (that we import directly in the project) are installed from a requirements.txt file with explicit version numbers. We added the version numbers after noticing our new deployments (which rebuild Docker/dependencies etc) would sometimes install newer versions of the packages, causing the project to break.

The issue we're facing now is that an onboarding developer is setting up her environment and facing the same issue - this time with sub-dependencies of the original dependencies. (For example, Flask might install Werkskreug, Jinja2, etc and if some of these are the wrong version, the app breaks.) The obvious solution is to go through each sub-dependency and list out every package, with explicit versions, in requirements.txt. But this is a bit of a pain so I'm asking around to see what people do on Real Projects.

You guys can't be doing this all manually, right? In JS we have NPM and package.lock files and so on - they're automatically built. Is there some equivalent in Python? Have I missed something basic that we should be using here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should have a look at `pipenv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a tool that might be helpful for this called [realreq.](https://github.com/Calder-Ty/realreq). You can install it from pip `pip install realreq`. It will generate the requirements you have by reading through your source files and recursively specifying their requirements.

`realreq --deep -s /path/to/source` will fully specify your dependencies and their sub-dependencies. Note that if you are using a virtual environment you need to have it activated for realreq to be able to find the dependencies, and they must be installed. (i.e realreq needs to be ran in an environment where the dependencies are installed). One of your engineers who has a setup env can run it and then pass the output as a requirements.txt file to your new engineers.